# How to get consecutive rows given a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I've got a table that looks like this

```
    WeekId     PassesCondition
----------------------------------
      1              1
      2              0
      3              0
      4              1
      5              1
      6              1
```

I need to write a query that counts the consecutive weeks back from the max `WeekId` that the condition has been passed.

I've done some searching and I seem to need to do something with a `CTE` and `ROW_NUMBER()` possibly. I've tried a few things, but the results haven't even been worthy to post as a "What I've tried so far".

The output should be just a count of how many weeks from the `Max(WeekId)` was the condition passed. e.g. 1, 2, 5, etc.

Comment: what should the output be? what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the condition is only `0` or `1`:

```
select count(*)
from t
where t.weekid > (select max(t2.weekid) from t t2 where t2.passesCondition = 0) or
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.passesCondition = 0);
```

The second condition is unnecessary if you know a row with `passesCondition = 0` exists.

If you like using window functions, you can also do this with a cumulative reverse min:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             min(passesCondition) over (order by weekid desc) as running_min
      from t
     ) t
where running_min = 1;
```

Or, `not exists` can be used:

```
select count(*)
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.weekid > t.weekid and t2.passesCondition = 0
                 );
```

Or `> all`:

```
select count(*)
from t
where t.weekid > all (select t2.weekid from t t2 where t2.passesCondition = 0);
```

I hadn't realized there are so many different way to express this.  No doubt, there are quite a few more.

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to account for the multiple start and stops you can count the islands using a query similar to:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(WeekId INT, PassedCondition BIT)
INSERT @T VALUES (1,1),(2,0),(3,0),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1),(7,1),(8,0),(9,0),(10,1)

;WITH Holes AS(SELECT WeekID FROM @T WHERE PassedCondition=0),
SegmentStart AS
(
    SELECT WeekId, HoleWeekId 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  This.WeekId, HoleWeekId = MIN(H.WeekId)
        FROM  @T This
        INNER  JOIN Holes H ON H.WeekId > This.WeekID AND PassedCondition=1
        GROUP BY This.WeekId
        UNION 
        SELECT WeekId = MAX(WeekID), HoleWeekId=MAX(WeekID)+1 
        FROM @T 
        WHERE PassedCondition=1
    )AS X
)
SELECT 
    WeekSegmentEnd = HoleWeekId-1,
    ConsecutiveCount = COUNT(*)
FROM 
    SegmentStart
GROUP BY
    HoleWeekId
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the rows that are between the *maximum* `weekid` that has `passesCondition = 0` (exclusive) and the *maximum* `weekid` (exclusive):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tablename t
WHERE 
  (t.weekid < (SELECT MAX(weekid) FROM tablename))
  AND
  (t.weekid > (SELECT MAX(weekid) FROM tablename WHERE passesCondition = 0));
```

If you want to include the last `weekid` you change `<` to `<=`.